# Convert a const into a function in JavaScript - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

How can I convert his constant into a function? I think is better to have a function that a constant this long. It does a filter and then a map.

```
const cells = upcoming
  .filter(clinic => {
    if (showAll) return true;
    if (
      clinic.staff.teamLeadStaffed !== null &&
      clinic.staff.techsStaffed.length === clinic.staff.techsNeeded
    )
      return false;
    return true;
  })
  .map(clinic => {
    const [color, reason] = this.getColorAndReason(clinic);
```

I tried something like this but it didn't work

```
  renderCell(upcoming) {
    return (
      upcoming
        .filter(clinic => {
          if (showAll) return true;
          if (
            clinic.staff.teamLeadStaffed !== null &&
            clinic.staff.techsStaffed.length === clinic.staff.techsNeeded
          )
            return false;
          return true;
        })
        .map(clinic => {
          const [color, reason] = this.getColorAndReason(clinic);
    )
  }
```

Comment: you are missing the closing brackets for the `map` function. `})`

Answer (score 1):

```
function cells() {
  return upcoming
    .filter(clinic => {
      if (showAll) return true;
      if (
        clinic.staff.teamLeadStaffed !== null &&
        clinic.staff.techsStaffed.length === clinic.staff.techsNeeded
      )
        return false;
      return true;
    })
    .map(clinic => {
      const [color, reason] = this.getColorAndReason(clinic);
    });
}
```